# Submitting form doesn't refresh page properly

Tags: php, html, forms

This form is located within a table and generated via PHP. Everything works well and it appears that the page is refreshing but it actually does not. If I submit the form, then manually press refresh the browser asks if I want to resubmit the data. However, if I go directly to the URL it does not ask this.

The data is successfully submitted to a DB so it is working, its just not refreshing properly. What am I missing?

```
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <form id='form9' method='post' action=''>
                        <input type='date' name='date' value='2015-01-27'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='1234'>                                                
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='result' form='form9'>
                      <option></option>               
                      <option value='option_a'>A</option>
                      <option value='option_b'>B</option>
                      <option value='option_c'>C</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='info' form='form9'>
                      <option></option>               
                      <option value='option_1'>999</option>
                      <option value='option_2'>888</option>
                      <option value='option_3'>777</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input form='form9' type='text' name='comments'/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input form='form9' type='submit' value='Save'>
                </td>               
            </tr>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`submit` button should be inside the `form` definition, wrap every element inside `form` definition

Answer (score 0):

The forms closing tag is written right after two inputs and than followed by other inputs, which is wrong. Closing form tag `</form>` should encompass all form elements. Below is the corrected version that should work.

```
         <tr>
            <td>
                <form id='form9' method='post' action=''>
                    <input type='date' name='date' value='2015-01-27'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='1234'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name='result' form='form9'>
                  <option></option>               
                  <option value='option_a'>A</option>
                  <option value='option_b'>B</option>
                  <option value='option_c'>C</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name='info' form='form9'>
                  <option></option>               
                  <option value='option_1'>999</option>
                  <option value='option_2'>888</option>
                  <option value='option_3'>777</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input form='form9' type='text' name='comments'/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input form='form9' type='submit' value='Save'>
                </form>
            </td>               
        </tr>
```

It does not matter where exactly will the closing form tag be, as log as it wraps all forms' elements.

Comment: I corrected as per your suggestion but the behavior has not changed. It still does not properly refresh. Can it be something else?

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out. It had to do with the order of the code on my page - so it was reloading but the data I needed to display was in the wrong area.

Comment: Okey, it is great that found the solution. :)